# TFS 2018: Copy artifact to server

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

I'm using TFS 2018 to automatically build a Cypress Creator Projekt via cmd line tools. After a successfull build I want to copy only my .hex file to another server, not the whole directory.

I followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/build-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic):

[image]

My Publish Artifact looks like this:

[image]

Error message: "PathToPublish is not found."

If I change the PathToPublish like this:

[image]

It works without any problem. So I think there is a syntax issue here.

**Question:** How to publish just a specific file instead of a whole directory?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t specify files in Publish Build Artifact task in TFS 2018. For your requirement, you can add Copy Files task to copy necessary files to a folder, then publish this folder:

[image]

[image]